# Mapped Picklist field values in a wrapper class in incorrect format

Tags: apex, schema

I want to retrieve the picklist values of all picklist fields from a standard object. Below part of the code

```
 //Wrapper class 
public class FieldMetaDataWrapper {
   @AuraEnabled
   public String fieldapiname {get;set;}
   @AuraEnabled
   public String fieldtype {get;set;}
   @AuraEnabled
   public Boolean isPicklist {get;set;}
   @AuraEnabled
   public List<String> picklistValues {get;set;}

   public FieldMetaDataWrapper(String fieldapiname,  String fieldtype, Boolean isPicklist, List<String> picklistValues){
       this.fieldapiname = fieldapiname;
       this.fieldtype = fieldtype;
       this.isPicklist =isPicklist;
       this.picklistValues =picklistValues;
   }
}


 @AuraEnabled
  public static List<fieldMetaDataWrapper> getFieldMetaData(){

    List<FieldMetaDataWrapper> fieldData = new List<FieldMetaDataWrapper>();
    Set<String>fieldAPINames =  new Set<String>();

   <Code to get all the fieldAPINames of the Object>

   // map of all fields in the object
   Schema.DescribeSObjectResult descSobj=User.getSObjectType().getDescribe();
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> objectFields = descSobj.fields.getMap();
    Map<String, List<String>> pickValuemap = new Map<String, list<String>>();
    List<String> pickvalues = new List<String>();

   // iterate over the requested fields and get the describe info for each one.
    for(String field : fieldAPINames){
      Schema.DescribeFieldResult dr = objectFields.get(field).getDescribe();
      Schema.DisplayType isPick = dr.getType();
      List<Schema.PicklistEntry> pl = dr.getPickListValues();
      if(String.valueOf(isPick) == 'PICKLIST'){
         for (Schema.PicklistEntry a : pl){
           String name = a.getValue();
           pickvalues.add(name);
          }
          pickValuemap.put(field, pickvalues);
          fieldData.add(new FieldMetaDataWrapper(field, String.valueOf(dr.getType()), true, pickValuemap.get(field)));
      }else{
          fieldData.add(new FieldMetaDataWrapper(field, String.valueOf(dr.getType()), false, null));
    }


return fieldData;
}
```

But in the wrapper object, wherever the ispicklist boolean is true, all the picklist values of all fields are getting added. For example  for the **statecode** picklist field, the JSON list comes as below. Can't get my head around as to why the entire list is being added here .

```
{
    "fieldapiname": "statecode",
    "fieldtype": "PICKLIST",
    "isPicklist": true,
    "picklistValues": [
        <<Entire picklist values of all picklist fields of the Object>>
         ]
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're initializing the `pickvalues` only once, so you're really just updating the same list over and over again. To demonstrate this clearly, try this code:

```
String[] a = new String[] { 'Hello' };
String[] b = a;
b.add('World');
System.debug(String.join(a,' ')); // Output is "Hello World"
```

You need to move this line:

```
List<String> pickvalues = new List<String>();
```

To here:

```
  if(String.valueOf(isPick) == 'PICKLIST'){
    List<String> pickvalues = new List<String>();
```

This will give you a new object for each picklist.

---

P.S. You can use the enum directly:

```
  if(isPick == Schema.DisplayType.PICKLIST){
```

It's slightly longer but avoids the runtime conversion and possible typos.

---

P.P.S. Don't forget about the MULTIPICKLIST and COMBOBOX varieties (if applicable).

Comment: @Brav You're welcome! Always glad to help.